# Python's run_in_executor aspects

Tags: python

There is `run_in_executor` in Python to perform blocking operations in a thread pool so they don't block the main thread.

1. What are performance limits for run_in_executor? I didn't find specific information about it. I understand that the answer depends on many factors, but I want to understand in general. For instance, I do queries to database through sqlalchemy 1.1.13, and these queries are wrapped in run_in_executor, queries are almost the same and they run in 0.5 sec on database server each. Is there a limit of parallel queries number can be run through run_in_executor?
2. I use tornado web server, version is 4.5.2. Run_in_executor could be called through `asyncio` and through `tornado`
   What is the difference? Is one of them better than another?

```
import asyncio
...
loop = asyncio.get_running_loop()
...
result = await loop.run_in_executor(...
```

and

```
from tornado.ioloop import IOLoop
...
await IOLoop.current().run_in_executor(...
```

3. New version of sqlalchemy supports `async`. Is async sqlalchemy similar to not async sqlalchemy with all queries wrapped in run_in_executor? Or there are significant differences?

Comment: You pass a thread pool to `run_in_executor`, and you specify the size of the thread pool when you create it.  That limits the number of tasks that will run in parallel.  The rest will queue up and wait their turn.

Answer (score 1):

`run_in_executor` doesn't decrease the delay of the operations, an operation that takes 0.5 seconds will still take 0.5 seconds, the difference is that the main thread is not blocked and can execute other async tasks, so the throughput of the entire server is increased and it can server more clients concurrently.

keep in mind that the executors are python threads which also need the GIL, so the throughput is increased only for IO bound tasks like database polling, not for computations, and this assumes your database can be polled concurrently (which most databases are).

for the number of workers, by default it is a default ThreadpoolExecutor which uses

> Changed in version 3.8: Default value of max_workers is changed to
> min(32, os.cpu_count() + 4). This default value preserves at least 5
> workers for I/O bound tasks.

which is a maximum of 32 workers by default, you can change that by using the [`loop.set_default_executor`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/asyncio-eventloop.html#asyncio.loop.set_default_executor) function which you can use another [ThreadpoolExecutor](https://docs.python.org/3/library/concurrent.futures.html#concurrent.futures.ThreadPoolExecutor) with the number of workers you want. the other limit is on how many threads you OS allows you to launch, but that is usually thousands unless limited by some admin settings, and executors don't launch threads unless needed, so you won't run into that.

keep in mind that WSGI like gunicorn will lunch a base number of threads so that number will increase or decrease the attainable concurrency depending on the WSGI and threads used.

running it through tornado is just one less import, [there is no difference.](https://www.tornadoweb.org/en/stable/ioloop.html)

> In Tornado 6.0, IOLoop is a wrapper around the asyncio event loop